# Cannot write into VMware Fusion shared folder from Arch Linux

Tags: network-shares, arch-linux, vmware-fusion

I am using a VMware Fusion virtual machine with Arch Linux for development on my macOS host.

I have created a shared folder named `dev` with *Read & Write* permissions.

[image]

I have been able to successfully mount the Shared Folder on my virtual machine with the following fstab entry:

```
.host:/dev    /home/victor/dev    fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other,nofail,nonempty  0 0
```

Now this works, the Shared Folder is successfully mounted. If I go into the mount point and `ls -l`, the owner of the files and directories appears as numeric IDs, and I get `permission denied` when trying to create files/directories in there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install the vmware tools in the guest OS?

Comment: @HenrikPingel yes I did. I would not even get read access otherwise, right? The `mount` would fail